# Cannot resolve symbol 'OnMapReadyCallback' Issue

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest

I am following Google Maps Android "get started" tutorial- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

But I came across an error ""Cannot resolve symbol 'OnMapReadyCallback', which might be a easy fix, but is baffling me. This is the code I have for my import statements for the app:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class main extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    // Within which the entire activity is enclosed
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    // ListView represents Navigation Drawer
    ListView mDrawerList;

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle indicates the presence of Navigation Drawer in the action bar
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // Title of the action bar
    String mTitle="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="temp.com.temp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >




        <activity android:name="temp.com.temp.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="temp.com.temp.Register"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBCCBIgQMw3XgIK4eQHndGHHlzvcT7vgwQ"/>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
</manifest>
```

Main Layout File:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- Google Maps -->
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Perhaps you are pulling in an older version of Maps V2. If you are using Android Studio, try `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'` in your `dependencies` closure.

Comment: Perfect! That worked,  thanks a lot CommonsWare!!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`OnMapReadyCallback` just came out in a recent update to the Maps V2 SDK. If you want it, you need to upgrade to a new-enough version of that SDK.

Android Studio users can switch over to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'`, from [the new Play Services granular dependencies](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html), to get this new class and possibly reduce the size of their APK as a side benefit.

Comment: Gradle gives me `failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87`. How do I resolve this?

Comment: @udiboy1209: Make sure that you have the latest Google Repository installed via the SDK Manager.

Comment: Yea I found that fix elsewhere :P . Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: I wish you would get hired by Google to write their docs. There docs have so many holes....

Comment: @CommonsWare I am getting trouble in this. onMapReady is not called even once.. i am using google play services 9.2.0 as i am using firebase also. Please help

Comment: @Pihu: I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest google repository in your SDK. Also Add the google map dependecy : implementation `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1`. You can find the latest dependency version [from here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).