# How to call getMapAsync() from an activity

Tags: android, dictionary

I am trying to call getMapAsync() from An Activity but I got this error:

Error:(109, 14) error: cannot find symbol method getMapAsync(CategoryActivity)

```
public class CategoryActivity extends Activity implements     View.OnClickListener,OnMapReadyCallback {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);



    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapContainerLayout);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining a private Class implementing the OnMapReadyCallback Interface
and passing that object.

Comment: it's the same code that Evin1_ posted if you are still getting that error that means that your dependencies aren't right add the line that he posted to your gradle.build and make sure you are targetting the latest SDK see this for more info/code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527783/cannot-resolve-symbol-onmapreadycallback-issue

Comment: Thank you ... After I update the sdk and idk to the lastest version it is work now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an anonymous callback:

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.a_main_maps);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: ");
    }
});
```

---

Also, make sure you have the latest version of the play-services dependencies (9.2.0):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
```

[Add Google Play Services to your project](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

Comment: I get this error now >>Error:(111, 14) error: cannot find symbol method getMapAsync(<anonymous OnMapReadyCallback>)